# How to install JBoss AS 7 in Eclipse Juno

Tags: jboss7.x, eclipse-juno

I'm using Eclipse Juno and My Application runs on JBoss 6. Now we are migrating from JBoss 6 to JBoss AS 7. I'm not able to configure the JBoss 7, when i add download additional server adapter, none of the adapter's are shown in the wizard. I also tried manaully by Help->Install New Software and using this link  http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/nightly/core/trunk/ but it says some context.xml not found.

Is there any way, i can use the JBoss 7 with eclipse juno version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'have added `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` to eclipse.ini and it solved the problem. May be it's related to some proxy settings.